# Why is a plane needed to represent something tangent to a point with two inputs rather than a line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question comes from watching Khan Academy's introduction to Tangent planes [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=H2hOwKszKRo) He extends the concept of a tangent line in two dimensions, a line that shares the same slope of a function at a point, to a plane, sharing the same slope of a point in 3 dimensions. However, to my knowledge, a tangent has always to me been a line that touches a function only one time. However, for tangent planes, it can touch a surface multiple times, so how can it be called tangent? And, my other confusion is titular for this thread: why is a plane necessary to illustrate the slope of the surface at a given $(x_0,y_0)$ instead of a line? I know lines really only appear in R3 as solution lines but I can't think of a good reason as to why lines couldn't represent the slope of one point of a surface.

Comment: The tangent line to $y=\cos x$ through $(0,1)$ also touches the graph several times, so that is not a criterion

Comment: The tangent line to a curve $y = f(x)$ at the point $(t, f(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as the line through the point $(t, f(t))$ with the slope of $f^\prime(t)$. NOT as a line that touches the graph only twice, and the definitions are not the same as given in the example above.

Comment: @AsafHaas and Hagen von Eitzen Fair enough, but regardless, why is a plane necessary rather than a line to represent the slope at two input points?

Comment: Try to visualize to yourself why for most points on a 3 dimensional curve I can find infinitely many line candidates of being the "tangent line", and try to convince yourself that all this lines lie in the same plane

Comment: @AsafHaas Is it sort of like saying I can rotate the tangent line any way and it will still describe the slope at that input space, and by that extension it forms a plane?

Comment: Something like that. The thing is that you can think about the slope in every direction (a directional derivative) and therefore the tangent plane contains them all

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to explain this: tangent plane contains all tangent lines in 3d space, if you wish, as we can draw infinitely many lines that touch a 3d shape at a particular point.

Also, the slope of a tangent line for function $f(x)$ at point $a$ is defined by a derivative $f'(a)$. In 3d space we have $f(x,y)$ so we have two lines with different slopes ($df/dx$ and $df/dy$). These lines intersect at the tangent point and we know that there is a unique plane that contains two intersecting lines.

Finally, the equation for a tangent line in 2d is $y=ax+b$, don't you expect it to be $z=ax+by+c$ (which is a plane equation) in 3d?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are considering surfaces presented in the form $z=f(x,y)$, but that you have not yet grasped the idea of a tangent plane even in an elementary geometry sense. Consider the three **examples**
$$({\rm i})\quad  z=x^2+y^2,\qquad ({\rm ii})\quad z=x^2,\qquad ({\rm iii})\quad z=xy\ .$$
In each of these examples the $(x,y)$-plane is the tangent plane to the surface $S: \>z=f(x,y)$ at $p=(0,0,0)\in S$. In case  (i) the tangent plane has just $p$ in common with $S$, in case (ii) the tangent plane at $p$ is also tangent at all points $(0,y,0)$, $y\in{\mathbb R}$, and in case (iii) the tangent plane at $p$ intersects $S$ along the two lines $x=z=0$ and $y=z=0$, but is only tangent to $S$ at $p$.

It turns out that we need a sufficiently powerful definition of the notion of "tangent plane". One such definition is the following: Given a point $p\in S$ we can consider  smooth curves on $S$ passing through $p$. Each such curve will have a tangent at $p$ which can be computed using differential calculus. The set of all these tangents a priori could form a "broom", or a "hedgehog", but it so happens that all these tangents are lying in a single plane through $p$, and this plane is the *tangent plane" to $S$ at $p$.

Try to grasp these facts, and then come back asking subsidiary questions.